# How do I get the MoreLinq namespace installed for a solution using .net 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-3.5, morelinq

I know I have done this before using a NuGet package.  For some reason I keep getting this error when I try to install it.  Maybe I need an earlier version of the NuGet package, but I can't seem to find one anywhere.  If the version is the problem, does anyone know where to get one that will work with .net 3.5.
[image]

I'm sure that from my question you can tell I'm not a trained programmer, so please tell me if I just have this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the path is pointed to the folder where the `nuget.exe` resides then open up a Command Prompt and type

```
c:\temp\> nuget install morelinq -version 2.9.0
```

Inside the `c:\temp` directory you will get a directory `morelinq.2.9.0\lib`. You will see a folder for net35, net40, netstandard1.0, netstandard2.0